# ayuda laravel SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found:

Tags: laravel

Estoy trabajando con laravel 5.8 y he creado mi modelo Person y la migracion persons hasta ahi todo bien se migra correctamente pero al momento de llamar a todos los datos de mi tabla persona me sale este error 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
en mi controlador de persona tengo esto en el index

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Person;  // aca llamo ami clase persona el modelo persona
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PersonController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $person = Person::paginate(); // llamos a los datos de mi db y los pagino
        return view('persons.index', compact('person'));
    }
```

y aca tengo mi modelo

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Person extends Model
{
    protected $fillable =['name','apellido','edad','address'];
    //
}
```

y aca la migracion

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePersonsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('persons', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('apellido');
            $table->string('edad');
            $table->string('address');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('persons');
    }
}
```

Comment: Laravel por defecto espera o esta buscando una tabla llamada people, en tu modelo agrega esto `protected $table='Person';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es una buena práctica definir el nombre de la tabla que se va a utilizar con un modelo, esto con el fin de mantener una consistencia de definir la tabla en todos los modelos, y para asegurar que siempre estamos trabajando con la tabla que fue creada en la migración.

En ese orden de ideas, agrega lo siguiente al modelo Person, idealmente al comienzo de la clase:

```
/**
 * The table associated with the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'persons';
```

Como siempre, revisa la documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions

Comment: gracias por la ayuda si me sirvió bastante y eso me ayudo pero ahora seguiré y me leeré una ves mas ese manual de laravel